# machine learning,sklearn kfold,where the different betweent clfs?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have used kfold to create 10 classifiers.
Now I need to choose one classifier to predict.
Is one of these classifiers better than the rest or are there no difference between the classifiers?

```
kf=KFold(10,True)
sum_jing=0
sum_recall=0
for train_index,test_index in kf.split(x2):
    x_train,x_test=x2.loc[train_index],x2.loc[test_index]
    y_train,y_test=y2.loc[train_index],y2.loc[test_index]
    #clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, max_depth=2, random_state=0,class_weight="balanced")#balanced比较准0.93#0.7
    #clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=0,class_weight="balanced",max_depth=2,max_features="auto")#0.93#0.83
    clf= RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=0,class_weight="balanced_subsample",max_depth=2,max_features="auto")#0.93#0.73-0.89
    clf.fit(x_train,y_train)
    #print("精度",clf.score(x_test,y_test))
    y_predict=clf.predict(x_test)
    sum_jing=sum_jing+clf.score(x_test,y_test)
    sum_recall=sum_recall+metrics.recall_score(y_test,y_predict,)
    #print("召回率",metrics.recall_score(y_test,y_predict))
print(sum_jing/10)
print(sum_recall/10)
from sklearn.externals import joblib
import os
os.chdir("chen")
joblib.dump(clf, "train_model.m")
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are comparing three different RandomForestModels?
They might be all the same, depending on how much the hyperparameters actually have an impact on the resulting model.

Unless you are very sure that these three are the only alternatives at hand,
I would recommend hyperparameter tuning.

Scikit learn provides e.g. grid search or random search which lets tries all/many combinations of parameters, returning the best combination.

So perform GridSearchCV and RandomizedSearchCV prior to the code shown above.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html

To get more information regarding the concept:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html

Comment: Because my data is unbalanced，so i choose kFold to accurate evaluation my models.I think i can use all date to train a new  randomforest models becauese 
I am satisfied with the result of kfold.